# How to create distribution of Python GTK3 app?

Tags: windows, gtk3, python-3.7, mingw-w64, software-distribution

I made an application using GTK3 on Windows (Mingw_x64 installation of GTK) and I cannot really figure out how to make a distribution out of this. According to official documentation of PyGObject, it is possible in some way.

I already tried to make a package using setuptools, but PyGObject documentation is not saying much about this process and I was not able to configure setup correctly to make it work. PyGObject has a lot of dependecies and weird imports, that I do not know how to include.

I also tried Pyinstaller, which claims it has GTK support, and it really can pack it into executable, however it is not working. I tried these two options:

1. make only one file (.exe), but in this situations, it throws an error, that some file is not found (libpixbufloader-ani.dll)
2. create a directory with all needed files (libpixbufloader-ani.dll and other libs are included this time), but when running exe, another exeption occurs, this time Struct and 2 other libraries are missing (strangely, there is a folder that contains Struct)

Becouse of the missing files, I tried adding as many paths containing needed libraries as possible to Pyinstaller, but without success.

Does anyone have any experience with packaging GTK appliciations in Python? There is definitely a way to do this, but I am not very experienced with packaging. If needed, I can provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that has been brought up on [PyInstaller's GitHub page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4125), as others (including myself) have experienced the same issue that you've mentioned.

The last time I tried the dev version of PyInstaller, the issue still wasn't fixed, but I managed to get a working executable by using PyInstaller to find the dependencies that my Python3/GTK3 app needed, and then I used cx_Freeze to generate the final executable.